# Can i mix two spring declarative features like @Cacheable and @Transactional on same method?

Tags: java, spring

I need to make my service method both cacheable and with transaction support feature by using declarative Spring mechanisms. I just want to know is Spring capable for resolving multiple proxying for method invocation without any not acceptable side effects.

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implement Service {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao dao;

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "cacheName", sync = true)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Result produceResult(String arg1, Integer arg2, Integer arg3) {
        Object obj = dao.getSomething(arg1, arg2);
        ...
        Result res = dao.getResult(obj, arg2, ...);

        result res;    
    }

    ...
}
```

Does it work properly ?